# How do I remove a line of the form ARRAY=...; with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to learn sed, but I encountered a problem. Let me explain, I have a file called in:

```
code..
ARRAY=(anystring);
code..
```

where anystring means that there can be the code I want to, since it's only an example. Now with sed i want to remove the line "ARRAY=...;"

I tried with:

```
sed "/#ARRAY=.*;/d" in > out
```

But with no success, while:

```
sed "/ARRAY=[a-z]*;/d" in > out
```

Is working fine for me. The problem is that after "ARRAY=" there can be all the characters (except of ; obviously).

How can I do this?

Comment: You may want to go back and accept some answers to older questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/^ARRAY=.*;/d' in >out
```

The beginning of the line is expressed as ^, not #. If you accept leading whitespace, as suggested by Swiss in the comment, use

```
sed '/^[ \t]*ARRAY=.*;/d' in >out
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the '#' character in the first command. The '#' character has no special meaning in sed regex.

Answer (score 1):

`sed "s/^ARRAY=.*;//g" <in >out`
Or better yet `sed "/^ARRAY=.*;/d" <in >out`

The "s" means, substitute. So `s/ABC/DEF/` means replace ABC with DEF. The "g" means global, so it will remove all such lines, instead of only the first one. `^` means, the line must begin with ARRAY

Comment: I don't think this answer is really addressing the question correctly. First, it unnecessarily uses the 's' switch instead of the 'd' switch. Second, it ignores the fact that whitespace may come before 'ARRAY'. Third, it glosses over the fact that the actual error lies in the REGEX.